# Pasar arreglo de componente padre a componente hijo Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy usando la librería ng2-chart y deseo pasar la informacion de un componente padre al comonente hijo.
La informacion la obtengo desde una API que me proporciona los datos.
Pero no está cargando la informacion:

```
export class PruebasComponent implements OnInit {

  lineChartData: ChartDataSets[];
  lineChartLabels: Label[];
```

En el `ngOnInit` obtengo la data

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;


    this.datos.getDesktopLimit().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.data = [res];
        this.dataSource = this.data[0];
        this.barChartData = true;
        this.getFilter(this.dataSource);
      }
    )
  }
```

y a través de la funcion `getFilter()` logro modificar los datos que quiero enviar:

```
  getFilter(data) {

     data.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
    for (let entry of data) {
      this.date.push(moment(entry.created).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'))
      this.time.push(entry.total_load_time * 0.001)
    }

    this.lineChartData =  [{ data: this.time, label: 'Time Render' }]  /* [ { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A' }] */;

    this.lineChartLabels = this.date;

    this.loading = false
  }
```

`[datasets]` està enviado el dato vacio

```
 <app-graphic [datasets]="[lineChartData]" [labels]="lineChartLabels"></app-graphic>
```

Comment: Quitale los [] y solo envia lineChartData
[datasets]="lineChartData"

Comment: Otro posible problema es que el componente se genera antes de que tu objeto "lineChartData" este lleno y por eso se envia vacio tal y como esta declarado

Comment: Ya lo acabo de quitar, pero el componenet hijo recibe un `undefined` [datasets]="lineChartData"

Comment: Es la segunada opcion que me estas dando, dado que paso el arreglo hardcodeado en el ngoninit y funciona, pero tambien los paso en el funcion getfiler no los envía

Comment: <app-graphic *ngIf="!this.loading" [datasets]="[lineChartData]" [labels]="lineChartLabels"></app-graphic>

Comment: Intenta cargar tu componente hasta que la data haya sido cargada en tu variable, segun veo usas la variable "loading"

Comment: @GFlores98 Gracias, esta opcion funciono

Comment: Publicare la respuesta, para que tu pregunta se marque como respondida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta cargar tu componente hasta que la data haya sido cargada en tu variable, segun veo usas la variable "loading"

```
<app-graphic *ngIf="!this.loading" [datasets]="[lineChartData]" [labels]="lineChartLabels"></app-graphic>
```